# Bulk Insert csv file into Azure

Tags: azure, import, ssis

I want import a csv data file straight into a table i've created in Azure. I understand that Bulk Insert isn't supported in Azure.

Please can anyone suggest a method for importing a flat file straight into Azure - I want to be able to do this straight from the command line (so that I can monitor the execution time using **set statistics io on;** ), and without syncing through SSIS or other applications. I've searched for guidance on this but all the articles I find appear to reference using BCP, but this appears to be an add-in?

Grateful for any suggestions.

R,
Jon

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem, could you elaborate a bit? For Azure, are you talking about Windows Azure SQL Databases (hosted SQL Server) or are you talking about an Azure hosted VM that has SQL Server installed on it? Next point is on BCP, what? I mean, I suppose you could call it an add-in but it's a very vanilla add-in that comes with SQL Server. It *sounds* like you're trying to get something related to timings, what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Hi @billinkc. It's Windows SQL Azure (cloud hosted) i'm referring to. I've created a database and would simply like to import a flat file of data directly into it (in a similar fashion to how you would use a BULK INSERT command in SQL Server to achieve the same exercise).

Answer (score 4):

I've actually used the method stated here: [Bulk insert with Azure SQL](http://thecodegarden.net/bulk-insert-azure-sql/).

Basically you bulk insert your data to a local MSSQL database (which is supported).
Create a txt file with all data and bulk insert it into your azure table by using the BCP command in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the same as Jefferey, but in case the site goes down here's the syntax:

```
BCP <databasename>.dbo.<tablename> IN <localfolder>\<filename>.txt -S <servername> -d <database> -U <username>@<servername> -P <password> -q -c -C -t ;
```

The `-C` enables you to use UTF-8 as needed for cases with special chars (like æøå).